# Jest mock node module not working with typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, ts-jest

I try to mock the module `uuid/v4` coming from npm. 
To do that, I have created a mock folder as suggested by jest : https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

My folder structure :

```
├──__mocks__ 
|  └──uuid
|       └──v4.ts
├──src
│   └──__tests__
│   └── ...
├──node_modules
```

The mock node module file **v4.ts** :

```
module.exports = jest.fn();
```

When I try to import uuid/v4 in my test file, jest should normally import the mock and I should be able to play with it.

Here my test file :

```
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';

it('should create a job', () => {
    const jobId = 'fake-job-id';
    uuidv4.mockReturnValue(jobId); 
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, the mock import seems not working because I can't add the `mockReturnValue` provided by jest and I have the following typescript error : 
`property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type v4. ts(2339)`

Do you have any idea how I can fix that please ? Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A common way to handle a situation like this is to auto-mock the module in the test, then tell TypeScript the module is auto-mocked by using `jest.Mocked` like this:

```
jest.mock('uuid/v4');  // <= auto-mock uuid/v4

import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';
const mocked = uuidv4 as jest.Mocked<typeof uuidv4>;  // <= tell TypeScript it's an auto-mock

test('hi', () => {
  mocked.mockReturnValue('mocked result');  // <= use the properly typed mock
  expect(uuidv4()).toBe('mocked result');  // Success!
})
```

Unfortunately the typing for `uuid/v4` doesn't seem to work right with this approach.

As a workaround you can use a type assertion:

```
jest.mock('uuid/v4');  // <= auto-mock uuid/v4

import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';

test('hi', () => {
  (uuidv4 as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue('mocked result');  // <= use a type assertion
  expect(uuidv4()).toBe('mocked result');  // Success!
})
```

Comment: Thank you Brian it works perfectly ! I have noted that it works also just with : 
`jest.mock('uuid/v4');  const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4'); ` 
and without need of type assertion.

Comment: Awesome, good to hear!  Yeah, using `jest.Mocked` is ideal since it maintains type safety, but since the typing doesn't work right in this case either the type assertion (some type safety) or `const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');` (`uuidv4` is type `any`) work fine as workarounds.